# Xamarin Android FlyOutMenu by Garuma - Multiple Screens

Tags: android, xamarin

So I'm using Garuma's FlyOutContainer class in my project (http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/04/19/fly-out-menu-xamarin-android/)

But I'm having trouble using the menu to change the content layout. Whenever I remove a view from the content layout and inflate another, it draws the entire content layout at 0, 0 so when the menu layout closes, it drags the content layout past the left edge of the screen as well!

I've been looking for answers and fiddling with this for days now, so I thought I'd ask if anyone here has run into this issue and fixed it as well.

Alternatively, a layout that I could hold static to switch between several other layouts might work as a solution, I just haven't been able to find one that could do so that worked with this FlyOutContainer.

Thanks in advance for any and all replies!

-Sibley

Comment: do you have any code to share to show what you've been working on that isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `DrawerLayout` which Google supplies in the `Support.v4` packages, which shows the standardized version of the FlyOut/Sliding/NavMenu which has been implemented in various ways previously, including FlyOutMenu.

I have a sample showing both `DrawerLayout` and `SlidingPaneLayout` in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/DrawerSample).

One thing to notice is that `SlidingPaneLayout` is not meant for navigation, while `DrawerLayout` is. The former is meant as a responsive design, where a Pane's visibility is toggled in portrait mode, while always visible in landscape mode.

Comment: And the DrawerLayout is similar to the slide-out-from-left navigation of applications like Google+ and the like?

Comment: Yes. It is exactly what Google+ provides as navigation in their app.

Comment: I'll take a look and let you know if this is what I was looking for! Thank you SO much for your quick and informative reply